# Adding Font + Feature to Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, size, font-size

I'm trying to create a feature for the Script Encoder that I'm creating that will increase the *font size* of the textarea by one. This is what I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var size=10 + "px";
  var size2=10;
  function add(){
     size2++;
     size=size2+"px";
  }
  if(typeof size2=="undefined"){size2="10";}
  $('#panel').html("<form method='post' name='pad' align='center'><textarea class='look' rows='11' id='code1' style='font-size:"+size+";' name='text' cols='58'></textarea><br></form>")   
</script>

<div id="panel"></div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Font+" name="fontAdd" onclick="add();">
```

The problem is that the Textarea is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ammended your solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9Y/2/

The only 'gotcha' is that if there is text in the textbox when the size of the text is increased, it doesn't really stay inline properly until you start typing again. You'll see what I mean, but hopefully that's solved your main problem.

**Edit**: A bit of padding makes the issue a lot less noticable
http://jsfiddle.net/H2J9Y/3/

Comment: WOW Thanks...I will be trying out the padding. Also I noticed you added that little counter for the font size. It seems like were kinda on the same page when it comes to web designing. I had this already installed to my site and it will be very useful.

You can look at the full script encoder here: http://yolatools.yolasite.com/script-encoder.php

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead

```
<div id="panel"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Font+" name="fontAdd" id="fontAdd">
```

I added an `id="fontAdd"` and then referenced via `click()`

```
$('#fontAdd').click(function(){
  size2++;
  size=size2+"px";
  if(typeof size2=="undefined"){size2="10";};
  $('#panel').html("<form method='post' name='pad' align='center'><textarea class='look' rows='11' id='code1' style='font-size:"+size+";' name='text' cols='58'></textarea><br></form>");
      });
```

Also, you were missing a few `;`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/n3jGK/

**Keep clicking the `font +` button to see the increase.

Comment: Um, this just makes the textarea bigger. I clearly said font size!

Comment: @Shawn31313, type in the textarea.  Each time you click on the size, it increases the fontsize.  But I wasn't fixing that.  Your problem...which you wrote above was `The problem is that the Textarea is not showing!`  I fixed that!